# Download and add Chromebinary in environment variables

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, selenium-chromedriver

Background - I am moving from `Nightwatchjs` to `Cucumber-jvm`.

In `Nightwatchjs` project, I was able to install and run automation test cases on latest `Chrome binary`. It was handled programmatically with in the project with the help of below JS code.

```
var path = require("path");
var selenium = require('selenium-download');
var binPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'bin');

selenium.ensure(binPath, function (error) {
  if (error){
    console.error(error.stack);
  } else {
     console.log('. Selenium & Chromedriver downloaded to:', binPath);
  }  
  process.exit(0);
});
```

As of now I have automated the steps using Selenium+Java, browser automation:

1. Go to https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
2. Click on latest binary
3. Unzip it in required path directory

But it looks time consuming, error prone, it is not as quick as it was JS.

To implement this:

1. Either I run given JS using Java https://javapapers.com/core-java/run-javascript-from-java/ but then problem is I want to make code OS specific. E.g. For Windows download windows binary and for Linux download Linux binary, which is not available in given JS code
2. I write same implementation in Java from scratch.

Question: How can I implement same approach in Java, with OS compatibility? I am not that good in Java, my Java knowledge is limited to browser automation only.